# Disable add to cart button for specific product categories in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, custom-taxonomy

I am developing an ecommerce website using woocommerce. I have two product categories:

1. Juices
2. Cleans
   And i intend to sell subscription from the website.

**Scenario:**

When a user selects a product category and fills in the number of days of subscription and relevant details then the user is redirected to that product category page to be able to add products to cart.

**Problem:**

I need a way to disable add to cart button for other category products like if Juices is selected the cleans should be disabled and vice versa. so that user can select only one type of subscription in a purchase to keep the system hassle free.

What is the hook or way in woocommerce to do it?

Comment: can you share your development URL or DOM

Comment: Please provide some more info. your question is not clear do you want to hide or remove add to cart button for Juices's category products?

Comment: I want to allow only 1 product category in cart.

Comment: So when a product from 1 category is added to cart products from other category should not be allowed to be added to cart

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this task using following code in your theme's functions.php file.

```
//Remove add to cart button
function remove_add_to_cart_button()
{
   global $product;
   global $woocommerce;  

   // start of the loop that fetches the cart items
   foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values )
   {
       $_product = $values['data'];
       $terms = get_the_terms( $_product->id, 'product_cat' ); // Get all assigned categories 
       $_categoryslug='';       
       foreach ($terms as $term) 
       {
           $_categoryslug[] = $term->slug;   // Get category slug to compare
       }
   }

   // Check if cart item is added for one category then restrict all other categories product
   if ( !has_term( $_categoryslug, 'product_cat', $product->id ) )
       remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
}
  add_action('wp','remove_add_to_cart_button');
```

This code is working for me so I hope it will helpful to you as well.

Comment: This will remove add to cart button for 1st item too

Comment: This code is tested so it should work for you as well, if still not work for you then can you please share how those products with categories screen-shots? So I can check with the same scenario.

Comment: This code is not working in my case

Comment: Also i want to remove add to cart button from product category page